# getting import error while importing flask _wtf from flask in my main.py file that is app.py

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

Below is the code for registration and login form :

```
    from flask_wtf import Flaskform
    from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,SubmitField,BooleanField
    from wtforms.validators import DataRequired,Length,EqualTo
    
    
    class RegistrationForm(Flaskform):
        username = StringField('Username',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=20)])
        password = PasswordField('Password',validators=[DataRequired()])
        confirm_password = PasswordField(' Confirm Password',validators=[DataRequired(),EqualTo('password')])
        submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
    
    class LoginForm(Flaskform):
        username = StringField('Username',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=20)])
        password = PasswordField('Password',validators=[DataRequired()])
        remember = BooleanField("Remember Me")
        submit = SubmitField('LOGIN')    
 
the main file is app.py:
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from login import RegistrationForm,LoginForm


#media for the project
import os
prerna = os.path.join('static','pic.png')
prerna2 = os.path.join('static','Untitled.png')
prerna3 = os.path.join('static','wardrobe.png')
video = os.path.join('static','DigitalWardrobe.mp4')
prerna4 = os.path.join('static','BUUTON.png')
prerna5 = os.path.join('static','start.png')
prerna6=os.path.join('static','home.jpeg')

#create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
#Database connenction
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///loginForm.db'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'f79e06501f31fae1c771ee83cc8c3868'


#initialize the database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

'''class is the table created in the database'''
class loginForm(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(8), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name %r>' % self.id
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

#path for the pages
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",img = prerna2,img1 = prerna,img2 = prerna3,vid=video)

@app.route('/home')
def home() :
    return render_template("home.html",title='home',button=prerna4,home=prerna6)  

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    return render_template(register.html,title='Register',form=form)

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    form = loginForm()
    return render_template(login.html,title='login',form=form)    




# @app.route("/login",methods=["GET","POST"])
# def login():
    
#     return render_template("login.html")   

@app.route("/createyourcloset")
def createyourcloset():
    return render_template("createyourcloset.html",start=prerna5)     

@app.route("/opennewcloset")
def opennewcloset():
    return render_template("opennewcloset.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
        
    app.run(debug=True)
```

error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\digifit\login.py", line 1, in 
from flask_wtf import Flaskform
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flaskform' from 'flask_wtf' (C:\Users\lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\digifit\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_wtf_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Typo Error: The Class is called `FlaskForm` not `Flaskform`

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
```